# Why doesn't padding-bottom in div tag work?

Tags: html, css

I have a `<div>` and I want to put the text 10px from bottom border of the `. However, it doesn't work for me. Following is the code.

```
<div id="title" style="height:35px;border-bottom:thin solid rgb(65,31,30);margin-left:14px;padding-bottom:10px;font-size:18px;font-weight:thicker">Hello, world!
</div>
```

Comment: you are missing a `;` after the word thicker

Comment: @rsz The last one can be omitted.

Answer (score 3):

remove your `height:35px` style. that contradicts what you are trying to do. it has a 35px height plus an additional 10px bottom padding.

check out this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lat8v/). i hope it makes sense to you.

Comment: Why does height contradict padding? What if you have a fixed-height element that’s supposed to have some spacing between its inner border and its text content?

Comment: With current CSS, you can use `box-sizing: border-box` to avoid this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have experiences with this sort of stuff in the past. This is just the case in some browsers and especially if you had `overflow-y: scroll;` enabled in the style. Your syntax looks good and I have tried it. even with or without that semi-colon at the end, it would still work fine since you are styling it inside the div as an attribute itself.

The way I see it if this is not your entire code please be aware of `overflow: scroll;` it code be overwriting your style.

or try running it with other browsers.

or you could restructure your code to make sure the padding works like this:

`<div id="title" style="height:35px;margin-left:14px;font-size:18px;font-weight:thicker">Hello, world!<div style="border-bottom:thin solid rgb(65,31,30);padding:10px">&nbsp;</div>
</div>`:

by just adding another div within that div